# VueJS 3 : "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**main.js**

```
import Vuex from "vuex"
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from "./store"
import drizzleVuePlugin from "@drizzle/vue-plugin"
import drizzleOptions from "./drizzleOptions"


const app = createApp(App)
app.use( Vue, Vuex, store,drizzleVuePlugin, { store, drizzleOptions })
app.mount('#app')
```

Im using VueJS 3. Im getting this in my terminal:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure but I used these codes and they worked.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```